# Setting of property doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I have the channels:

```
<div id="panel">
            <pre class="channel" id="one">ONE</pre>
            <pre class="channel" id="two">TWO</pre>
</div>
```

I want to mark a channel with property in this way:

```
function onSelectChannel()
{
    // callback
    var foundChannel = $(this);
    var prevSelectedChannel = $("[selected='true']");

    if (foundChannel.size() > 0) {
        foundChannel.css('background-color', selectedChannelColor);
        foundChannel.prop("selected", "true");

        if (prevSelectedChannel.size() > 0){
            prevSelectedChannel.css('background-color', channelsColor);
            prevSelectedChannel.prop("selected", "false");
        }
    }
}
```

I can find *foundChannel* and set property(I can see it inside debugger), but I can't find objects with already set properties. jQuery returns nothing.

UPDATE: I want to mark some(irrelevant which one) element with a mark (it can have any name), I mean: set any value to attribute or property — I don't care, and than find this element at any time. And this is only what I want.

Comment: Have you tried `attr` instead?

Comment: `prop()` doesn't update DOM attribute so your selector `[selected='true']` won't match anything. BTW, `selected` attribute is not valid on `pre` element. Why don't you use a class instead? And FYI, `size()` is deprecated, you should use `length` property instead

Comment: @putvande yep, it's not what I need.

Comment: @cassandradied Rereading your code, why don't you just toggle a class???

Comment: @A.Wolff are you sure that it doesn't update anything? I can see updated value in the debugger. Maybe 'selected' *attribute* is not valid, but I want to use properties, not attributes, and set to it any values. Pre element could be changed to any other element soon, so, it's irrelevant which tag actually I will use.

Comment: @cassandradied `prop()` update the property, not the attribute. But you are using attribute selector, this cannot return what you are expecting. If you use property, you could filter it then using `.filter(function(){return this.selected]);` but then use boolean for `.prop()` method: `.prop("selected", true);` and `.prop("selected", false);`

Comment: See there: http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/13/ or maybe this one to exclude clicked element http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/14/ That's said, i'd still suggest you to use class instead but maybe you are not just looking for styling behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff if you add your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating property with `.prop()` jQuery's method, you need to filter set of elements. You cannot use attribute selector in this case.

### --DEMO--

```
function onSelectChannel() {
    // callback
    var foundChannel = $(this);
    var prevSelectedChannel = $(".channel").not(this).filter(function () {
        return this.selected
    });

    if (foundChannel.length > 0) {
        foundChannel.css('background-color', selectedChannelColor);
        foundChannel.prop("selected", true);

        if (prevSelectedChannel.size() > 0) {
            prevSelectedChannel.css('background-color', channelsColor);
            prevSelectedChannel.prop("selected", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `$(this)` in a function, you should create a click handler with jQuery, for example:

```
$("#panel .channel").click(function() {
    var foundChannel = $(this); //This DOES work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`selected` is a property for `<option>` tags. So i think it can't work on `<pre>` tags.

You should use something else like `data-selected`.

```
var prevSelectedChannel = $('[data-selected="true"]');
//...
foundChannel.attr("data-selected", "true");
//...
prevSelectedChannel.attr("data-selected", "false");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class for it.

```
$(function(){
    var $channels = $('pre.channel');
    var onSelectChannel = function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $channels.not(this).removeClass('selected');
    };   
    $('#panel').on('click', 'pre.channel', onSelectChannel)
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JGpaX/2/)

To find selected item use:

```
var $selected = $('pre.selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` object  is nothing in your case, as it is used in a seperate module and the scope of  `$(this)` is null.

But the same would have worked if `$(this)` was  inside a click event handler like this

```
          $('<selector>').on('click',function (){
                   $(this);//refers to the current object/element which triggered click event  
           });
```

So instead of defining `onSelectChannel()` outside the event handler, better define it within the event handler itself as a anonymous function.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I guess OP is already calling `onSelectChannel()` from any relevant event: `I can find foundChannel and set property`